# How to update a browser cookie in real time using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I need to update a cart cookie as soon as a button is clicked, without the page refresh. I am using the below code:

```js
$(function(){
 $("#cookieUnset").click(function() {
       count--;
           Cookies.set("cart",count);
           $("#cart_value").html(count);
       });
    $("#cookieSet").click(function() {
       count++;
           Cookies.set("cart",count);
           $("#cart_value").html(count);
       });
});
```

```html
<div>
 <button class='btn btn-success' id='cookieSet'> Add to cart</button> 
 <br> <br>
</div>
<div>
 <button class='btn btn-danger' id='cookieUnset'> Remove from cart</button> <br> <br>
</div>
```

but, the cookie value is updated only when I refresh the page.

Comment: How are you determining that the value hasn't changed? For the code you've provided, it makes no difference to any visible output if the cookie is set immediately or on page reload. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: I can see the value in cookies section of the browser and it gets updated only when I refresh the page.

Comment: Why does that matter?